# Dependency in pom refers to a parent pom which when running locally fails

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a service where I have added dependency which contains relative path to a parent pom. When I try to build this locally, the local build fails complaining that its unable to find the parent pom.

Suggestion to overcome this issue so that I can build the project locally

Comment: ask an author of dependency to publish valid pom

Comment: The relative parent-pom path in a pom of a dependency should be irrelevant, since they are only needed to build the dependency; when built, the parent pom should be resolve through the dependency system (e.g. through mvnrepository). Please [edit] the post and add the (relevant part of the) `pom.xml`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.